# How is cookie data for a site being created or updated for a site I do not visit?

Tags: firefox, cookies

In Firefox, I noticed that I have updated cookie data for a site I don't visit. How is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Could be in an iframe for a site you *do* visit...

Comment: @Mokubai I installed NoScript and it showed that sites I visit are connecting to social networks like Facebook or analytics like Google. I believe when the script from that social network runs it updates it's cookie. I would like to add this as an answer.

Comment: Feel free to do so, it would be good to close the loop and have a method of how to go about finding what was causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed NoScript and it showed that scripts on the page were pulling in java script code from different social networks. It would make sense if they embed share links but they also appear to be creating cookies.

Here is a screen shot from NoScript:
[image]

Since installing the update I've noticed many sites are linking to the social networks and advertising networks.

I've also turned off accept cookies from third parties in the browser settings menu. The cookies have not been updated since.